# SQL help needed in removing a sub-query

Tags: sql, db2, subquery

I have a poorly performing SQL that contains a sub-query that is not co-related. I replaced it with a co-related sub-query but performance got worse. Is there a way to rewrite this SQL by removing the sub-query entirely and replacing it with a join?

Below is a simplified version of the query:

```
    select distinct tab1.app_id, 
            tab1.name, 
            tab1.stat_cd, 
            tab1.qr 
    from apps tab1 , issues tab2 
    where 
            tab1.app_id = tab2.app_id and 
            tab1.qr = 'm' and 
            tab2.iqr = 'm' and 
            tab1.app_id not in 
            ( 
              select  distinct tab3.app_id 
              from issues tab3 
              where tab3.iqr = 'm' and 
              ( 
                 tab3.i_cd = 'f' or 
                 tab3.i_cd = 'r' or 
                 tab3.i_cd = 'c' 
              ) 
            )
```

Any tip or assistance is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The `distinct` in the sub-query is useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

other solution

```
select distinct tab1.app_id, 
        tab1.name, 
        tab1.stat_cd, 
        tab1.qr 
from apps tab1 
inner join issues tab2 on ( tab1.app_id, tab1.qr)= ( tab2.app_id, tab2.iqr) and tab1.qr='m'
left outer join issues tab3 on ( tab1.app_id, tab1.qr)= ( tab3.app_id, tab3.iqr) and tab3.i_cd in ('f', 'r', 'c') 
where tab3.app_id is null
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly as well. I don't have enough of a data set to determine which of your two solutions is faster, nor do I have the explain plan as of now. But with the limited data set I have, your second query appears faster. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much help this will be, but I would like to hear back on how it does...

```
SELECT DISTINCT tab1.app_id,
       tab1.name, 
       tab1.stat_cd, 
       tab1.qr
FROM apps tab1
JOIN issues tab2 ON tab1.app_id = tab2.app_id
JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT app_id AS app_id
       FROM issues
       WHERE iqr = 'm'
         AND ( i_cd = 'f' OR
               i_cd = 'r' OR
               i_cd = 'c'
             ) 
     ) tab3 ON tab1.app_id = tab3.app_id
WHERE tab1.qr = 'm'
  AND tab2.iqr = 'm';
```

Comment: Sorry - just reread the question.  Please try my modified code.

Comment: Thank you, toonice. I am unsure what you meant by the last predicate (AND tab1.app_id;). Taking it out, the query returned fewer rows than expected.

Comment: That was left over from when I removed the `NOT IN` subquery - I should have removed that part as well.  My apologies for the confusion.  Also, is returning fewer rows a good or a bad thing?  If the latter, then what didn't it return?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
 select distinct tab1.app_id, 
            tab1.name, 
            tab1.stat_cd, 
            tab1.qr 
     from apps tab1
     inner join
     issues tab2 
     on 
     tab1.app_id = tab2.app_id
     left join
     issues tab3 
     on
     tab1.app_id = tab3.app_id
  where     tab1.qr = 'm' and 
            tab2.iqr = 'm' and
            concat(tab3.iqr,tab3.i_cd) not in ('mf','mr','mc)
```

Hope this helps:-)

Comment: I think the `tab3.iqr = 'm'and ` in the `WHERE` clause would make the `LEFT JOIN` an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @mrtig yup. Thanks for pointing that out. It's a mistake from my end

Comment: Thank you, India Rocket. This query returns more rows than expected. It is a very creative solution though and I am sure will work with a bit of tweaking :)

Comment: @pdfella check it now and let me know whether its working

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select distinct tab1.app_id, 
        tab1.name, 
        tab1.stat_cd, 
        tab1.qr 
from apps tab1 
inner join issues tab2 on ( tab1.app_id, tab1.qr)= ( tab2.app_id, tab2.iqr) and tab1.qr='m'
where not exists 
( 
          select  * from issues tab3 
          where ( tab1.app_id, tab1.qr)= ( tab3.app_id, tab3.iqr)
          and  tab3.i_cd in ('f', 'r', 'c')
)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you, Esperento57.